# A speedometer like chip

Tags: accelerometer, velocity

Is there a device which acts like an accelerometer but only measures absolute velocity? I could integrate the accelerometer's output but errors quickly accumulate and cause problems. Preferably the device is available in a MEMS based chip and is low cost. I could use a GPS device (and am currently, with success), but this is expensive, bulky, and requires a GPS link, which is not available in all circumstances.

Comment: How would such a thing even work?  It needs an external reference of some sort, like GPS or other positioning system.

Comment: @endolith Simple, its almost like measuring voltage with a single probe (no ground reference). Wait, not so simple :-)

Comment: I presume you mean without mechanical contact with a surface such as a trundle wheel and rotary encoder? Or a surface with stripes on it? That gives me a thought, do you mean like a laser mouse?

Comment: Perhaps if you describe your application, there might be some usable solution.  As others clearly pointed out, you can't simply measure velocity in a self-contained manner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such thing as absolute velocity; velocity is always relative to something.  Velocity cannot be measured internally to a chip (as can acceleration).  You must have external input, such as radio references a la GPS or sensors detecting changes in other phenomena external to the chip and its vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, there is no such thing as absolute velocity, however STM make a 3D motion sensing chipset (iNEMO). [Details of the evaluation kit here](http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/250367.jsp)